# Finding patterns in two files

Tags: python, regex, string, linear-algebra, pattern-recognition

I have to analyse 10 years worth of data and 50+ files for each year.
I extracted the data from the internet and all I have done is extracted the text with regular expressions.
The format for the files differ for each year and I'm not even sure that the pattern is consistent in the files of the individual years.
The format for 2003 seems to be

> title (.*)
>
> [header(.*)
>
> color number number number string (\w+\s\d+\s\d+\s\d+\s.+)
>
> color number number number string
>
> color number number number string
>
> color number number number string]<==== one block
>
> header
>
> color number number number string
>
> color number number number string
>
> color number number number string
>
> color number number number string
>
> ........

my question is, is there a way to program something in python to identify patterns within the text files of a given year?

A kind of pattern recognition, a program that outputs a regular expression that matches for one block of data perhaps.

I will be using this data for linear algebra, but I want the data to be easily accessible and organized for other uses.

Comment: You are trying to automatically generate a regex to match a set of files?

Comment: Yes, I do have an algorithm in mind, but its really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible maybe you should just go simpler and check to see if each line of each block of data has the same length when split by a space (or a tab, or whatever token divides each column). From there you could just create a tree from the data. Something like:

```
{title: {
    block: [
        [color, number, number, number, string],
        [color, number, number, number, string]
    ]
 }
 title:
     ...
}
```

If the data is too irregular for even that, you could try using third party libraries to either (1) clean up the html you are scraping the data from or (2) use natural language processing to tokenize/parse the data, but that seems like overkill.